# Indents in the <code> section not being recognized

Tags: c#

I have a code block in my XML comments -

```
    /// <code>
    /// {
    /// "partner": "1a",
    /// "subscriber": "E1",
    /// "ids": [
    ///     {
    ///         "id": [
    ///         "4ea333ae-740f-4afd-9d5e-3cfe898d8324"
    ///         ]
    ///     }
    ///   ]
    /// }
    /// </code>
```

This shows up in Swagger like so -

```
    {
    "partner": "1a",
    "subscriber": "E1",
    "ids": [
    {
    "id": [
    "4ea333ae-740f-4afd-9d5e-3cfe898d8324"
    ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

Is there a way for it to identify the indents I have specified in the code.

Comment: That is not a valid xml document. Please include the document and it's value. Also provide how you are displaying that document's value ("This is showing up like so...")

Comment: @Igor I have updated the question. Thank you

Comment: Try using [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)....

Comment: Please add `<pre>` nested in the `<code>`

Comment: Adding <pre> solved the issue. Thank you @KarolTrybulec